# Failed to use function

Tags: javascript, html

I can't use `put(element, content)` even after importing and exporting the function.

root/index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <meta name="title" content="${name}">
  <meta property="og:title" content="${name}">
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="Made using GBuild">
  <meta property="og:description" content="GBuild is untested web game builder">
  <title>${name}</title>
  <link href="style/build.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="module" src="script/build.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="container">Hello world</div>
  <script type="module" src="script/build.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="build/scripted.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

root/build/scripted.js

```js
put('h1', 'Hello Two')
```

root/script/build.js

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
function put (element, content) {
    return container.append('<br>', `<${element}>${content}</${element}>`)
}

exports.container = container;
exports.put = put;
```

Edit: `I did actually use express for this, so ${name} will replaced by it's value`

Another edit: `I already used <Express>.static() on 'script/' , 'style/' and 'build/'`

Even another edit: `Please see my` [REPLIT](https://replit.com/@discordlist/GBuil?v=1)

Comment: Additionally what CertainPerformance has answered, [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) doesn't do what you seem to expect it to do, and it's also useless to return the return value of `append` which is `undefined`.

Comment: So, how to import scripted.js to build.js without doing too many `export thing`

Answer (score 0):

ES6 modules are not CommonJS modules (and even in CommonJS modules, you still need to import from the other file, which you aren't doing). For `<script type="module"` - ES6 modules - you need to use the `import` and `export` keyword.

```
// scripted.js
import { put } from '../../build/scripted.js';
put('h1', 'Hello Two');
```

```
// build.js
export const container = document.getElementById('container');
export function put (element, content) {
    return container.append('<br>', `<${element}>${content}</${element}>`)
}
```

You don't need the `<script type="module" src="script/build.js"></script>` in the HTML, because it's now being imported directly by the other module file. It's usually a good idea to choose *one* entry point script, and to have everything branch off of that - it makes things far easier once a project really gets going.

Comment: Oh, why thank you ( if it is working )

Comment: But, is there a way to export them all without using too many 'export' keyword, since it will need to exports many things

Comment: I suppose you could also export a single object instead, with everything as members of the object. But explicitly noting which identifiers should be exported is a good thing, not a bad thing - it's a very clear way of noting what is intended for external consumption (and in well-designed scripts, a module shouldn't usually have more than one or two exports IMO - so it's not like you'll have to write it a lot)

Comment: 1. Thank you

2. I do need actually wrote  1 or more variable(s) and 4 or more functions

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. You don't need to write the same code twice or four times..?

Comment: It's not working, here's my [Replit](https://replit.com/@discordlist/GBuil?v=1)

Comment: You didn't export the `put` function. You only exported `data`, so it in `build`, it can't find the identifier `put`. Like in the code in the answer, you need to use `export` with the `put` function.

Comment: Yeah but, data is an object, and it has (put: put)

Comment: Yes, but you're trying to use `put` as if were a standalone identifier in `build`, which it's not, because you didn't export it or import it. Choose one - an object or a standalone function, and be consistent.

Comment: In fact, container is also undefined

Comment: Object (since i don't want to export them 1 by 1)

Comment: In the HTML, your `scripted.js` isn't being linked properly either, so things won't work anyway.

Comment: But you said to remove `<script type="module" src="build/scripted.js"></script>`...

Comment: Oh NVM, i read it wrong. I will tell you after testing

Comment: Read my answer again - it says to remove the `build`, because only your `scripted` is doing the real work - and your `scripted` isn't being linked properly, resulting in a 404 error - you can open the console on the page and see for yourself https://gbuil--discordlist.repl.co/

Comment: It is still the same

Comment: Huh, but `build/scripted.js` is only function and `script/build.js` is the main script 

Comment: Also, it doesn't send any console error since replit HTML DOM doesn't support console

Comment: You do not need anything special in order to open the console - all you need is a reasonable web browser, then press Control-Shift-I. The error is `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'` because your export syntax is wrong. Use `export` as I'm doing in my answer instead - before the identifiers to be exported.

Comment: I use mobile, that's why I can't see it.

Comment: But okay........

Comment: When writing code, you should really use a computer, else it'll be really difficult to do anything or debug with any efficiency.

Comment: And ofc, the same. Its error, and i don't know the error

Comment: I'm not a rich man that can buy a computer

Comment: This looks to be turning into a [chameleon question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions). You are running into too many problems unrelated to those in the question. Please try debugging them yourself - Stack Overflow is not here to be a substitute for the debugging capabilities of a personal computer.

Comment: If i can debug them, i would. But i can't, that's why I dont